# Pegar coordenadas do mouse somente quando clicar na tela

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho um problema onde preciso pegar a posição do mouse somente quando clico na div, ou seja, pegar a posição onde o mouse foi clicado dentro da div. Já consigo pegar a posição do mouse, com o evento "mousemove", porém ainda não consigo pegar a posição do click, no meu código, ele entra primeiro no clico, mas não pega o evento que esta dentro do click.

```
m_This.HtmlObject.click(function () {
      $(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {                
            var positionX = event.pageX;
            var positiony = event.pageY;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `click` ao invés de `mousemove`.

```js
var lastClickPosition;

document.addEventListener('click', storePosition, true);
function storePosition(e) {
  lastClickPosition = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
  console.log(lastClickPosition);
}
```

```html
<p>Clique na página</p>
```